# Angular5 and Bootstrap4 NavBar sticky-top

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap navbar position "sticky-top" works only if navbar is a direct child of

```
<body>
 <header class="sticky-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light p-0"> 
        ... 
    </nav>
 </header>
</body>
```

or

```
<body>
 <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-light bg-light p-0">
    ...
 </nav>
 ...
</body>
```

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21919

I have this code:

**index.html**

```
<body>
 <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-top-navigation></app-top-navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**topNavigation.component.html**

```
<nav dir="ltr" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-
top">
 ...
</nav>
```

And navbar isn't sticky and behave like fixed-top.
If I write:

**index.html**

```
<body>
 <app-top-navigation class="sticky-top"></app-top-navigation>
 <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Angular isn't see it. How can I make navbar sticky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `sticky-top` and `d-block` classes to your `app-top-navigation` tag:

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-top-navigation class="sticky-top d-block"></app-top-navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/SQtJRB9ReGOsmUi72SPG?open=app%2Fapp.component.html)**